# java concurrent map giving different size in diff class

Tags: java

I have one class like below: 
    public static volatile Map ResponseMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

```
    public static void addResponse(String sessionId, String response)
{
    PMMap.ResponseMap.putIfAbsent(sessionId,response);
}

    public static Map<String, String>  getDPMResponseMap() {
    return PMMap.ResponseMap;
    }

    public static String getDPMResponseMapValue(String sessionId) {
        return PMMap.ResponseMap.get(sessionId);
        }

and this is called by a class who reads value from a consumer and adds it to map like below:
PMMap.addResponse(sessionId, response.toString());
```

when i print here value in logs it shows correct size and value printed. 
 Same map i try to access from a different class where it shows map size as 0.

```
LOGGER.info("map size : " + PMMap.getDPMResponseMap().size() + "response: " +  PMMap.getDPMResponseMap());
```

can somebody help here..why map is showing size as zero. and i am not using any threadpoolExecutor service

Comment: 2 hints: 1. There's 1 map, but you call size() before put object in it. Check if there's race condition. 2. There's 2 maps. You load PMMap twice with different Classloader.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! i see in logs map gets filled first then it is read. but for loader thing i will change. but i have one doubt, normally we use it like this only, making map static and using it from ClassName.getMethod() . so why it should make a difference here?